# Spring MVC without annotation - HTTP 404 page not found error coming

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to write a simple Spring MVC web application without using annotations. However, when I access specific URL, I am getting HTTP 404 error. The relevant code snippet is below:

## web.xml changes done for front controller:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>POCProject</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The servlet name is --> **FrontController**

## Hence, have the following configuration file --> FrontController-servlet.xml

```
<beans ...>

   <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

   <bean name="/userdetails" class="com.example.controllers.UserDetailsController"/>

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value> </property>
      <property name="suffix"> <value>.html</value> </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

In above configuration file, the Handler mapping class is --> `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`

The controller class for URL `/userdetails` is --> `com.example.controllers.UserDetailsController`

## The code for this controller is below:

```
public class UserDetailsController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("userInfo");
    return mw;
    }
}
```

So, for a request with `/userdetails` the controller should send the view `userInfo.html`

However when I invoke this, I am getting HTTP 404 error.

I have deployed this in Apache tomcat, and the below is the message that I get in the tomcat console.

`WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/POCProject/WEB-INF/userInfo.html] in DispatcherServlet with name "FrontController"`

Any inputs on what I am missing here?

Comment: Well you have successfully configured the spring part because as the error is for not founding WEB-INF/userInfo.html, DispatcherServlet, controller, and Resolver all processed the request. First, does the file userInfo.html exist in WEB-INF folder? If it does, it is *uncommon* to redirect to html files because they will not the passed model, so you should use jsp files in your POC.

Comment: Add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your configuration.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks for your reply, informative indeed. The .html file exists in WEB-INF. I have doubt, why this can't a simple HTML file? Isn't HTML a view technology? I changed from .html to .jsp (and changes in the configuration ), and it working fine. Now I have this doubt, why can't we pass the html pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc for `InternalResourceViewResolver` says that it is a (emphasize mine):

> Wrapper for a JSP or other resource within the same web application. Exposes model objects as request attributes and **forwards** the request to the specified resource URL **using a RequestDispatcher**.

A JSP is internally converted in a true servlet by Tomcat (or by any servlet container) that is a resource suitable for forwarding. But a simple HTML is not.

That means that Spring `InternalResourceViewResolver` cannot use HTML views and you must convert them to JSP files.